# Configuration of fredhopper

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I am configuring Fredhopper (fredhopper-7.5-revision-15) as per the instruction mentioned on  [SDL live content](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D) manual for SmartTarget 2014. After executing on the command when I am browsing http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/admin/   am getting the below view with error message `Please wait The Business Manager will be available when the indices are loaded.`.

[image: fredhopper/Admin]

Here the GUI is supposed to ask the login credentials. I have also followed the steps mentioned on the Fredhopper site but no luck same response

Also, I have installed SmartTarget on Tridion 2013 SP1, I am getting the targeting option but unable to add a promotion.

Comment: I reformatted question and added error message in text for SEO.

Answer (score 6):

You will get the `Please wait  The Business Manager will be available when the indices are loaded.` message as long as Fredhopper indices are not built. You could say, the problem is that the Fredhopper system has no data.

To initialize Fredhopper you can either

- Copy the `SmartTarget 2014\Fredhopper extensions\data\metadata.xml` file from the installation media to the `<BASE_DIRECTORY>\<INDEXER>\data\fas-xml-incremental\<CATALOG01>` folder in Fredhoppper. See step 10/11 in the [Quick Guide](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D) and step 7 in the [Installing SmartTarget on premise](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8) section.
- Publish a SmartTarget enabled component presentation. That is a dynamic component presentation published with a component template, which has the `Add to SmartTarget` template building block.

Answer (score 2):

Run below command to get your fredHopper up and running.
Assuming you fredhopper installation is in e:\fredhopper
and assuming your Index Server name is SmartTarget you commadn will be.

bin\run-etl-job STJob.kjb "-DINSTANCE=SmartTarget" "-DTRIGGER=load-data" "-DUNIVERSE=catalog01" "-DEXECUTIONPATH=E:\fredhopper\data\instances\SmartTarget\custom\"

before calling this command do follow below step

Copy the **SmartTarget 2014\Fredhopper extensions\data\metadata.xml** file from the installation media to the \\data\fas-xml-incremental\