# configuration issue with fredhopper

Tags: fredhopper

I am getting this message when trying to login to fredhopper business manager.

> Please wait  The Business Manager will be available when the indices
>   are loaded.  (This page will refresh in 10 seconds)

I have followed the steps suggested by [Harish](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/10868/configuration-of-fredhopper) to run fredhopper without any demo content, but there is no luck. Can anyone suggest if I can login to business manager without demo content and before publishing dynamic component.

Comment: If this is in the context of SmartTarget, then you need to publish something into it before you can see any data here. See Jan's response: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/10871/33

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not so much an error but rather an indication that Fredhopper is empty. If you follow the steps outlined in the SmartTarget documentation, you will load a metadata XML file into Fredhopper to avoid exactly this situation.

Since you did not yet put any data into it, Fredhopper displays this message until such a time that you add some data. If you are using SmartTarget, you can simply publish some items with the "Add to SmartTarget" TBB and you should see the message go away shortly.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have added metadata.xml in catalog01 folder and then run STJob. But it was still showing the same message. I can understand after publishing it will work(verified by adding a fredhopper compatible component xml in catalog01 and then running ST Job). I wanted to install then test and then move to next installation. Can you suggest why my fredhooper is showing this message even after loading meta data xml file.

Comment: The only explanation would be that something went wrong when running the job and the data didn't get imported correctly. You can find out what went wrong by looking at the Fredhopper logs (incl. the ETL ones).